# SMC reset to fix battery not working, but cant be sure SMC reset has taken place

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, battery, power-management

I have had a new battery in my mid 2012 15" macbook pro running 10.11.6

The battery health as monitored through a battery health app downloaded from the mac app store has been deteriorating ever since i installed it and after about 3 months the battery is saying "Service Battery"

This doesn't tell the full picture though, as if it use my Mac once i get the "low battery 9 minutes remaining" warning, it will go on for hours without cutting out.

Ive been told i need to do an SMC reset to address the issue, but each time i do it following Apples guides for laptops with a removable battery, it dosnt fix anything?

How can I know that an SMC reset has taken place, can it be seen in the logs ? Or can i do an SMC reset through some kind of GUI tool which will give me feedback instead of the standard way which i cant be sure has worked.

Here is an output from About this mac > System Info > Power

```
Model Information:
  Serial Number:    REDACTED
  Manufacturer: SMP
  Device Name:  REDACTED
  Pack Lot Code:    0
  PCB Lot Code: 0
  Firmware Version: 2
  Hardware Revision:    00aa
  Cell Revision:    2
  Charge Information:
  Charge Remaining (mAh):   220
  Fully Charged:    No
  Charging: No
  Full Charge Capacity (mAh):   3918
  Health Information:
  Cycle Count:  81
  Condition:    Service Battery
  Battery Installed:    Yes
  Amperage (mA):    -1943
  Voltage (mV): 10877

System Power Settings:

  AC Power:
  System Sleep Timer (Minutes): 3
  Disk Sleep Timer (Minutes):   0
  Display Sleep Timer (Minutes):    3
  Wake on AC Change:    No
  Wake on Clamshell Open:   Yes
  Wake on LAN:  Yes
  AutoPowerOff Delay:   14400
  AutoPowerOff Enabled: 1
  Display Sleep Uses Dim:   Yes
  GPUSwitch:    2
  Hibernate Mode:   3
  PrioritizeNetworkReachabilityOverSleep:   0
  Standby Delay:    4200
  Standby Enabled:  0
  Battery Power:
  System Sleep Timer (Minutes): 10
  Disk Sleep Timer (Minutes):   0
  Display Sleep Timer (Minutes):    2
  Wake on AC Change:    No
  Wake on Clamshell Open:   Yes
  AutoPowerOff Delay:   14400
  AutoPowerOff Enabled: 1
  Current Power Source: Yes
  Display Sleep Uses Dim:   Yes
  GPUSwitch:    2
  Hibernate Mode:   3
  Reduce Brightness:    Yes
  Standby Delay:    4200
  Standby Enabled:  0
```

Here is an output from the command `system_profiler SPPowerDataType | grep -i "charge information" -A 10`

```
Charge Information:
          Charge Remaining (mAh): 234
          Fully Charged: No
          Charging: No
          Full Charge Capacity (mAh): 3918
      Health Information:
          Cycle Count: 81
          Condition: Service Battery
      Battery Installed: Yes
      Amperage (mA): -2579
      Voltage (mV): 10890
```

Comment: Please post the output of the command `system_profiler SPPowerDataType | grep -i "charge information" -A 10` to your question.  An SMC is just Apple's name for the PMU (power management unit) that every other laptop uses.  A reset will simply removed the saved values it measured up to that point; starts it off fresh.  There's no log and you cannot access it via a GUI

Comment: @Allan for instance i have been using my laptop for about 40 minutes right now since i had the low battery warning, saying i only had 9 minutes remaining

Comment: Thank you for posting more information. See my updated post.

Comment: Is it a genuine battery?

Comment: @JohnKeates its not a genuine battery, the original battery was old as it had been installed since i purchased the laptop in 2012. I was hesitant to get a 3rd party battery for obvious issues, but the apple store wanted to have my laptop in for 2 days (for a part i can swap out myself in 30 mins). The supplier was iFixit, who are reputable, so although its not an Apple original part, its not a eBay piece of rubbish. iFixit have agreed to send me out a replacement battery.

Comment: It is possible the battery management IC simply isn't communicating, or communicating bogus values. That causes the SMC to think the battery is bad and will trigger the warnings you see.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite possible you have a defective battery, bad cable or power handling chip issue on the logic board itself.  From the output you posted, here's what we know.

- 81 cycles and FCC of 3918 mAh is way out of specification
- The Voltage and charge measurement that you have 234 mAh (mili-amp hours) remaining
- It's showing a draw of approximately 2.5A (battery is being drained)

The SMC can only *accumulate* how much battery capacity is left by measuring the current power against the current draw and known full capacity.  In this case, it's measuring that you're out of power and indicating your battery needs to be serviced.

There's no "dipstick" that can give you the actual charge, the SMC *must* calculate it and from the data it's getting from the battery, it thinks it's failing even though it continues to work.

Your best bet is to replace the battery (it's probably still under warranty) and still more likely to be the cause if you were careful with the cables and reseated them.

Comment: Thanks @Allan , ill give that a try and let you know how i get on

Comment: Keep in mind that the bzq-series of gas gauge IC's used in pretty much all MacBooks do use the smart battery specification containing both design capacity, current capacity and status. This is matched against a number of power sensors on the MLB side which are read by the SMC. The SMC doesn't simply track and calculate (like the PMU did) but takes (correct) data from the smart battery in to account as well.

Comment: @JohnKeates our friend Allan needs bit more help from you explaining how it works. I am unable to accomplish that. He is stuck on believing the SMC actually `measures` battery parameters and there is no other circuit doing that, as you pointed out to him.

Answer (score -1):

Reviewing your Battery report:

Considering you installed it as "new" 3 months ago, unfortunately it behaves as 3- 5 Years old.

**The Full Charge Capacity (mAh) value is down to 3918 (<50%) !!** which is the absolute indicator of battery life, not so the cycle count.

(new battery comes with ~8200 mAh that gradually over 5 Years goes down), once it reaches below 50% you will get the Service Battery.

Replace it.

You current consumption `Amperage (mA): -2579` has nothing to do with anything, it is a variable that changes depending on the load.

If you plug in the Charger that number will go positive. (= Charging)

Also the remaining charge has nothing to do with battery life.

---

SMC can not read the battery values directly. There is a chip (IC) integrated with Battery called a SMBus chip or Gas Gauge or even Dipstick. It reads the analog values from the batter, coverts to digital and sends that to the SMC.

That is how it is possible for SMC to know the cycle count (and other values) even when you move the battery from one Mac to another.

[image]

An [SMBus battery](https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/inner_workings_of_a_smart_battery) contains permanent and temporary data. The battery manufacturer program the permanent data into the battery, which includes battery ID, battery type, manufacturer’s name, serial number and date of manufacture. The temporary data is added during use and contains **cycle count**, usage pattern and maintenance requirements.

To your second question ...How to see if SMC reset worked.

While doing it, watch the MagSafe plug light, it will briefly flickers if the reset was successful.

Comment: question updated with about this mac power info

Comment: i redacted the serial number and device name

Comment: @sam thank you, see my updated post with more information.

Comment: thanks, could you expand upon the MagSafe colour change, i wasnt aware i had to have the laptop plugged into the MagSafe whist running the SMC reset, also what colour dose it change to / from ?

Comment: You should read the article.  *The voltage is typically measured in 1mV increments; the current resolution is 0.5mA; temperature accuracy is about ±3ºC.*  The SMBus **measures** the *state-of-charge at that time* and does a calculation, it *cannot* act as a "dipstick" and tell you "there's this much charge remaining.

Comment: @Allan as long you learned that there something like the  SMBus specifically designed to provide battery information while physically attached to the battery, we can call it `dipstick` or what ever, but it is not the SMC chip as you wrongly claimed. For example the cycle count comes from SMBus not from SMC.

Comment: The SMC and macOS *calculates* time remaining based on information (voltage, charge, draw, etc.) it receives from the battery. You should also look up the definition of "dipstick" because it doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: @Allan now we are getting somewhere. In your post you wrongly state `The SMC can only accumulate how much battery capacity is left by measuring the current power against the current draw and known full capacity` and now we know the SMC is not measuring battery condition it is just reporting it against the Apple design parameters and informing the user when is the time to service battery.

Comment: Which is *exactly* what the SMC and macOS does.  The battery cannot tell you *how much time is remaining.* Period.  This is evidenced by the OP stating the macOS is saying "Service Battery" but the battery continues to function.  If it worked the way you describe, this condition couldn't possibly happen.

Comment: @Allan this is becoming a useless discussion. SMC does not `measure` Battery parameters. SMC it is a Digital Chip while battery parameters are all analog. The `Dipstick` as you call it is the SMBus chip which is A/D converter while mounted on the battery and it measures battery parameters including the Cycle Count, FCC among others. When you move the battery from one mac to another the Cycle count comes with it so does the FCC.

Comment: It is useless.  You keep attributing and addressing things I never said to me.  That said, you should re-read text in the link you provided.

Comment: The SMC does nothing more than acting as a sensor hub and making sure DC-DC circuits stay within safety bounds. There is a I2C bus where a 1-wire chips hangs off of which is connected to the magsafe (which contains a 1-wire switch chip connected to the center pin and switches the dual-color LED between green and amber -- but also contains a serial number which is read by the OS as the serial number and specification of the charger).

To the relevant part for this Q: macOS gets the battery data from the chip in the battery, this means serial number, state, factory spec and current spec.

Comment: For more information, download the schematics for a Mac of your choice and read the parts on DC-DC, 1-Wire, I2C and SMC. On the OS-side: use `sudo pmset -g rawlog` to get the data that is read from the battery chip.

Comment: In addition to all this data and facts gathering: the battery service alert decision is made on the OS-level (most of the time, if the SMC can't communicate with the battery but does read an extreme load for example, the machine might not power on at all and the SMC keeps resetting itself).

Items used by the OS: factory vs current capacity reported by the chip, cycles reported by the chip, power going in/out reported by the battery vs. reported by the I2C sensors.

Comment: In case the SMC reports something wrong to the OS while everything is actually fine is where you get to SMC resetting. Note: various things can turn a SMC bad, but often it's bad values set in the SMC, bad values being read by the SMC or the SMC power supply being crappy. Disconnecting a battery and reconnecting it when it is the only remaining power supply would do that sometimes for example. Same goes for a bad sensor (not the same as a missing sensor), or a chip on an internal bus that is there, but doesn't communicate.